# How do you check if Python turtles overlap?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I made a game in Python with the turtle module. I want to stop the turtles overlapping or, if they do overlap, move one of them to a different position. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
if turtle_1.distance(turtle_2) <= overlap:
     # your code here
```

where `overlap` is 1 for right on top to 10 for just touching.